# Facebook API - different results on localhost and production . Application request limit reached

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the following snippet:

```
$post_ids = array("307781172646235_739219686169046");
$quoted_post_ids = array();
foreach ($post_ids as $id) {
  $quoted_post_ids[] = '"' . $id . '"';
}


$fql = urlencode(
  "SELECT attachment FROM stream WHERE post_id IN(" . implode(',', $quoted_post_ids) . ")" 
);  

$all_photos_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=' . $fql . '&access_token=' . "XXXXXXXX";
$all_photos_result = drupal_http_request($all_photos_url);
$all_photos = json_decode($all_photos_result->data);
dpm($all_photos);
$actual_post = NULL;

foreach ($all_photos->data as $k => $post) {
  $actual_post = array();;

  foreach ($post->attachment->media as $photo) {
    if (isset($photo->photo)) {
      $photo_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $photo->photo->fbid;
      $photo_result = drupal_http_request($photo_url);
      $photo_info = json_decode($photo_result->data);
      if (isset($photo_info->images[0])) {
    $candidate_pic_url = $photo_info->images[0]->source;
    if (!empty($candidate_pic_url) && valid_url($candidate_pic_url)) {
      if (!isset($actual_post['picture_big'])) {
        $actual_post['picture_big'] = array();
      }
      $actual_post['picture_big'][] = $candidate_pic_url;
      $actual_post['picture_metadata'][] = $photo_info;
    }
      }
      usleep(500);
    }
  }

  dpm($actual_post);
}
```

The dpm() is just a Drupal-specific debug helper that outputs the variable. So the issue is that if I execute it at localhost, or on a staging server, it works, but on production, I do not have the image always via the graph API. Sometimes, I have, sometimes i does not have. It's a shared hosting at Gandi (https://www.gandi.net/hosting/simple) . Is it possible that the shared hosting itself becomes rate-limited?

Update:
On production, the second HTTP request gives: "Application request limit reached" OAuth Exception

Comment: Are your local, staging and production environments identical in configuration, or is there variance?

Comment: They're not identical, as you see, production is a 3rd party provider shared hosting, i cannot replicate these at local.

Comment: Ok, on prod, for the second HTTP request, I got this:
message (String, 38 characters ) (#4) Application request limit reached
type (String, 14 characters ) OAuthException, but it works fine at local with the same key.

Comment: The limits are on several levels. In your case I would guess IP is the problem